# Create Plugin to generate PDF files from content

Tags: plugin-development

Rather than render content out as HTML, I need to create PDFs for a project I'm working on. I was planning on using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) in a custom plugin, but having played around with it a little, it does seem very limited it terms of the HTML/CSS you can throw at it.

Are there any better solutions out there? It can either be PHP based or maybe Javascript instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering, it looks like I'll be going with [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io), it seems to have better HTML/CSS support than either [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) or [domPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (which [Printmaker](https://printmaker.docs.topshelfcraft.com) seems to be based on).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this one could help you: [Printmaker](https://printmaker.docs.topshelfcraft.com/)

Comment: Been using Printmaker on a project recently, and it's wonderful! The developer, Michael Rog, has also been extremely helpful and quick to respond.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was aiming more at the PDF creating side of things rather than the Craft Plugin side as the project would require something bespoke anyway. In hindsight, I guess the question is probably a bit too vague for the Craft Stack Exchange.